# repeated rows in json_agg() in query with 2 lateral joins

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a strange result when performing a lateral join on a query

I have the following table structure

```
task->id 
comment -> id , taskId, comment
tasklink -> taskId, type, userid
```

with a single task record (id 10), 1 comment record ("row1", "a test comment") and 5 tasklink records (all with taskid 10)

I expected this query

```
select task.id,
       json_agg(json_build_object('id',c.id, 'user',c.comment)) as comments,
       json_agg(json_build_object('type',b.type, 'user',b.userid)) as users

  FROM task 
  left join lateral (select c.* from comment c where task.id = c.taskid) c on true
  left join lateral (select b.* from taskuserlink b where task.id = b.taskid) b on true

  where task.id = 10    
  GROUP BY task.id ;
```

to return

```
id | comments                                   | users
---------------------------------------------------------------------
10  "[{"id":"row1","user":"a test comment"}]"   "[{"type":"updatedBy","user":1},"type":"closedBy","user":5},"type":"updatedBy","user":5},"type":"createdBy","user":5},{"type":"ownedBy","user":5}]"
```

instead, I got this

```
id | comments                                                                                                                                                                                           | users
10  "[{"id":"row1","user":"a test comment"},{"id":"row1","user":"a test comment"},{"id":"row1","user":"a test comment"},{"id":"row1","user":"a test comment"},{"id":"row1","user":"a test comment"}]"   "[{"type":"updatedBy","user":1},{"type":"closedBy","user":5},{"type":"updatedBy","user":5},{"type":"createdBy","user":5},{"type":"ownedBy","user":5}]"
```

ie , for every `link` row, the `comment` row is duplicated

I am thinking that I am missing something really obvious, but as I have only just started using Postgres (and sql ) I'm a little stumped

I would appreciate some guidance on where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the aggregates into subqueries:

```
select id, comments, users
from task t
left join lateral (
    select json_agg(json_build_object('id',c.id, 'user',c.comment)) as comments
    from comment c
    where t.id = c.taskid
    ) c on true
left join lateral (
    select json_agg(json_build_object('type',b.type, 'user',b.userid)) as users
    from taskuserlink b 
    where t.id = b.taskid 
    ) b on true
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=23fe99a18f601997ea129771d533b4de)

Comment: brilliant ! thank you , this indeed fixed the problem