# SQL error could not identify an equality operator for type json

Tags: sql, postgresql

I ran into this problem:

[repeated rows in json_agg() in query with 2 lateral joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069036/repeated-rows-in-json-agg-in-query-with-2-lateral-joins)

I got repeated rows on my columns so I want to try an example but now I got this error:

```
 error: could not identify an equality operator for type json
```

```
SELECT 
      p.id,
      p.shop_id,
      p.provider_id,
      p.name,
      p.status,
      
      c.product_options
      
      FROM product p
      
      left join lateral (
        select json_agg(json_build_object(
          'id', po.id,
          'p_id', po.p_id,
          'name', po.name
        )) AS product_options
      
        from product_options po
        
        where p.id = po.p_id
        
        ) c on true
      
      GROUP BY
      p.id,
      c.product_options
```

What I am doing wrong ?

[DB FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/be10d/14)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you cannot compare Json values. The group by part of your query is the one that is causing the issue since you are trying to group by a json field (c.product_options), which you don't even need. One solution will be to get rid off the group by as

```
SELECT 
      p.id,
      p.shop_id,
      p.provider_id,
      p.name,
      p.status,      
      c.product_options      
FROM product p      
left join lateral (
  select json_agg(json_build_object(
    'id', po.id,
    'p_id', po.p_id,
    'name', po.name
  )) AS product_options      
  from product_options po        
  where p.id = po.p_id        
  ) c on true;
```

Or, if you want to include it, you need to convert it to jsonb as

```
SELECT 
      p.id,
      p.shop_id,
      p.provider_id,
      p.name,
      p.status,      
      c.product_options::jsonb      
FROM product p      
left join lateral (
  select json_agg(json_build_object(
    'id', po.id,
    'p_id', po.p_id,
    'name', po.name
  )) AS product_options      
  from product_options po        
  where p.id = po.p_id        
  ) c on true
group by p.id, c.product_options::jsonb
```